# how can I avoid CPU waste (by master kernel) using WaitNext?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I'm using `WaitNext` in *Mathematica* for parallel processing on Mac OS X.  I have 4 processors on my MacBook and `LaunchKernels[]` has launched 4 kernels in *Mathematica*, in addition to the master kernel.  However, each of these 4 kernels gets approximately 75-80% of a processor, while the master kernel gets 70-75%.  It seems to me that the master kernel should be just waiting, instead of using CPU.

The relevant code is

```
While[Length[parallelJobs] > 0,
 {result, pJ, parallelJobs} = WaitNext[parallelJobs];
 Write[outputstream, result];
 setofresults = Join[setofresults, result]
]
```

where `parallelJobs` is a list of process IDs of the form `ParallelSubmit[{...},...]`, and each of the jobs should take about an hour.  Thus, there is no reason for the master kernel to be running.  A similar code with `WaitAll` instead of `WaitNext` leaves the master kernel with 0% CPU and gives 100% to each of the launched parallel kernels.  But the reason I want to use `WaitNext` instead is because I want to write the results as they're generated.  I'd be grateful for any explanation of what's going on or ideas for getting around this waste of CPU.  Thanks.

Later:

Here's a fix. I bundle more stuff into the `ParallelSubmit[...]` parts, in order to Write there, and then I use `WaitAll` on the list of `ParallelSubmit` items. This seems to result in considerably less overhead CPU used by the master kernel. It now seems to be an academic question: why does `WaitNext` (seem to?) use so much more overhead than `WaitAll`?

Comment: Welcome! Try to provide a small snippet of code that one can just copy and paste to see what you mean if possible

Comment: I formatted your code for readability. Please look what I did so you can reproduce it yourself.

Comment: Without digging into this, I'd just like to note that when the master kernel uses a lot of CPU it often indicates that a large amount of data is being sent back from the subkernels.

Answer (score 3):

This may be system or version dependent, as I don't get the same behavior. On Mathematica 8, OS X, using this line on a fresh kernel:

```
$ProcessID
WaitAll[{ParallelSubmit[While[True, Null]]}]
```

I get the same cpu utilization (70% main kernel, 100% parallel kernel), as if WaitAll is replaced by WaitNext.

In the following code, the parallel kernel gets a stack trace from the main kernel while the main kernel is running WaitNext:

```
seeStack[] := Stack[_];
SetSharedFunction[seeStack];
wait = ParallelSubmit[seeStack[]]
WaitNext[{wait}][[1]]
```

Based on the output, it looks to me like `WaitNext` checks for completed processes in a `While[True,...]` loop, hence the CPU usage. Very curiously, if `WaitNext` is changed to `WaitAll` the code does not terminate. If other expressions are submitted between the third and fourth line, they will execute normally (though I won't see the results because `seeStack[]` does not terminate).

My guess is that `WaitAll` is somehow integrated into the kernel and your implementation is more efficient than mine.

I learned about SetSharedFunction from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/local-logfiles-for-remote-kernels).